# insertar php en javascrip que ya esta mostrado por un echo

Tags: php, javascript

hola soy nuevo mezclando php en javascript me gustaria saber como puedo adaptar bien este foreach en esta sentencia de javascript para que se muestre correctamente la información

```
    $consulta= $obj->getQueryConsulta();
    $result = $catalogo->obtenerLista($consulta);
    $datos = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $datos[$row['datos']] = $row['series'];
    }


      echo "<script>Highcharts.chart('container', {

    title: {
        text: '".$obj->getDescripcion()."'
    },

    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: thesolarfoundation.com'
    },

    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: '".$obj->getDescripcion()."'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle'
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            label: {
                connectorAllowed: false
            },
            pointStart: 2010
        }
    },

  series: [
  ". foreach ($datos as $key => $value) {

  "{"    
       " name: '".$key."',

        data: [".for ($index = 0; $index < 12; $index++) {

"$value[$index],]"

  }

  }
      " }],


    responsive: {
        rules: [{
            condition: {
                maxWidth: 500
            },
            chartOptions: {
                legend: {
                    layout: 'horizontal',
                    align: 'center',
                    verticalAlign: 'bottom'
                }
            }
        }]
    }

});  </script>";
     break;

 la sentencia original de javascript es esta

    series: [{
        name: 'Installation',
        data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175]

    }],
```

Comment: que problema te da? no se entiende muy bien la pregunta

Comment: la pregunta no se entiende realmente el problema, pero viendo el código, estas haciendo un foreach dentro del echo, eso no se puede. Tienes que hacer las cosas por separado para que no te marque error

Comment: ok entiendo entonces reformulando como podría hacerle para mostrar la información de mi array de arriba  en en la parte de series